# How to create two windows (MDI+SDI) in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I am in a need to create two different type of windows, one MDI and one SDI in one application. I have tried to create an MDI application with document/view and put some codes to create an SDI window, but it failed. It seems MDI and SDI are created with different approach and I have no idea how to find a way to resolve it. Does anybody know the best way to do it?

---

After some tries, I managed to successfully create an SDI and a MDI window, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do. This is how I've done

Create an SDI application using Visual Studio's AppWizard, and I put the following code to create a MDI window when user clicks on SDI Frame's menu

```
CSDIFrame::OnClickCreateMDI()
{
CFrameWnd* pFrameMDI = new TestMDIFrameWnd;
CCreateContext Context;
Context.m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestMDIView);
if (!pFrameMDI->LoadFrame(IDR_TESTMDIFRAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, NULL, &Context)) {
AfxMessageBox("LoadFrame failed");
return FALSE;
}
pFrameMDI->InitialUpdateFrame(NULL, TRUE);
}
```

Is this correct way to do it? Can all the MFC programming methods be used on this newly created MDI window just like this MDI window is created using AppWizard? Will there be any limitation (such like some meesages can not be sent to this MDI window....)

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in the Win32 API preventing SDI and MDI from coexisting in a single app.  If you are having trouble using them, please [edit] your question to show what you have actually tried.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the code that I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries and study of MFC books and MFC source code, I have successfully create a MDI window from an SDI window. I can add multiple documents multiple panes to MDI. And exiting the application also OK without any error. It is not easy, there are some tricky parts to make this happen.

[image]